# z-index not working as expected on Google Chrome & Safari. Ok on Firefox & Opera

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, position, z-index

I have just finished the reading [this great post](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/), but it did not help me.

This is the website I am building: `http://82.230.210.84`. If you rezise Google Chrome down to trigger the responsive design, and then scroll down, you will see that the menu passes below the images, instead of remaining over them, as it does in Firefox.

In the code, all `z-index` properties come with a `position` property set to `relative`/`absolute`/`fixed`, and obviously the higher value (`50`) is set to the menu.

Any suggestion about why the menu does not stay on top on the images on WebKit browsers? 
Any potentiel fix/workaround is most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by adding `-1` z-index.

Like this

```
.formation_domains a.formation_domain > div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 125px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is exactly what I was expecting posting this, a good old workaround. I am amazed to see I did not think about it, but that does diminish the great hand you just gave me. 
Many thanks Mister. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I guess that sometimes being negative turns out to be a positive thing ;-) Glad it helped.